Trying to T-tap wires of different gauges. Do these t-connectors even exist?
I am new to wiring and need help with a new project.
I have a big box. On two sides of the box are 40 LED light strips; each light strip with a positive and negative wire. Theres a total of 80 LED light strips.
The positive and negative wires of the LED light strips are 18 AWG. Each positive wire requires 0.585 Amps to function. If theres 40 LEDS, that means there will be ~23.4 Amps for a single side.
I am considering T-tapping each of the 40 positive wires to a 10 AWG wire that can handle 23.4 Amps. However, Im concerned that this wont even work.
Can someone please help me with methods on how to connect these 40 wires to the power supply.
The following image is a rough diagram of what Im working with. I only drew 10 LEDS rather than 40 because I don't have time to draw them all:


Do you have multiple power supplies?

Yeah. I got two 960W 24V power supplies connected parallel. After speaking with the vendor they said the current is self-regulating so if an LED strip fails the others wont get an increase in current.

Yeah the power supplies are okay to be connected parallel, as far as I know.

Are the power supplies designed to be connected in parallel?  Connecting two 1kW power supplies together when they're not expecting it would lead to a very brief and expensive fireworks display. "As far as I know" should be "the datasheet explicitly states that it is allowed". It also doesn't look like you need to parallel them anyway.  For example, the last time I paralleled kW DC supplies, the voltages had to be manually trimmed to within 0.5% and then the power and voltage equalization signal lines could take over.

Yeah ive double checked and it can be connected parallel. I
got two of them in parallel because one cant supply enough power for the entire system. This particular vendor mean well dont make supplies with higher watts.

I dont think manual trimming of the voltage is necessary. These units are designed with automatic voltage and current balancing.

It doesn’t look like you need to parallel them, you should be able to run each side from one supply. Also you don’t mention the negative leads, they need to carry the same current as the positive leads, so if you need 10 gauge wire for one you need it for for  the other too.

I just realised that its so much simpler to keep them independent. Not sure why I made it way more confusing. Thanks

Could you tell us the dimensions? ... "big" is hard to guess, might be centimetres, might be a shipping container.

There are not a whole lot of elegant ways to split out that many taps from a single feed, but I've had success with buying plain copper bar stock (or silver plated if the budget allows) and drilling/tapping it to make a big busbar to which you screw down a whole bunch of...in your case probably #6 ring terminals. Just be sure to get some insulated standoffs to mount the bars.

Thanks for the answer. Ill have a look into your method!

Assuming your proposed solution it to use IDC taps (where the main wire is not cut at each tap only its insulation is pierced) then yes that could work.
There's a fairly large wire gauge difference, but something like 3m Scotchlok 567 could work here, but it seems fairly expensive.
You will probably be better served by using pre-fabricated ground bus bars like 'Siemens EC3GB212' (21 ways) - use 4 total.
You'll need to figure out a way to insulate them At 12V screwing  them to wood instead of to metal would be sufficient insulation.  As they could get warm an FDM 3D print is probably bad idea, but SLA in a heat resistant resin could work.
Separateing the strips into two groups of 20 instead of having one group of 40 will probably simplify the wiring and will also remove any concerns that stem from operating voltage sources in parallel.

A busbar should be a better choice than taps.
Something like this will get you 20 connecting points and is rated at 50 A. If you put two LED modules on each screw you could use two busbars per side, one for positive, one for negative. Four of them would run you around $100 US. You could probably make them yourself for less, but you have to decide how much your time is worth.
